# how to hide/show div section based on the value [Yes/No] from custom label in visual force page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

how to hide/show div section based on the value [Yes/No] from custom label in visualforce page.

Comment: What did you tried so far. Share the code.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications. That is not what comments are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring html div tag then we cannot use rendered condition with them. So here you can use `apex:outputPanel` with `layout="block"` attribute.

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="{!$Label.GatwayUserNotification == 'Yes'}">
     <!-- your content -->
</apex:outputPanel>
```

It will create div element for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apex:outputPanel` for this.

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!$Label.GatwayUserNotification == 'Yes'}">
     <!-- your content -->
</apex:outputPanel>
```

More on [Label](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_label.htm) and [apex:outputPanel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputPanel.htm)